# how i can to load Admob interstitial after 3 return from " layout ( recipes_detail ) " for example

Tags: java, android

i'm beginner in java and i need your help please, I want to load Interstitial ads after 3 return from  layout ( recipe_detail.xml )

### first i will explain the structure of this source code :

### [Files][1]

### [recipe_list.xml][2]

### RecipesList.java :

```js
    package com.villagetagh.halawiyatlaid;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
    import com.villagetagh.halawiyatlaid.R;
    
    public class RecipesList extends Activity {
     private InterstitialAd interstitial;
     ImageView imgAbout, imgSearchNav;
     Button btnSearch;
     EditText edtSearch;
     LinearLayout lytSearchForm;
     ListView listRecipes;
     ProgressBar prgLoading;
     TextView txtAlert;
        AdView ads;
     
     String RecipeNameKeyword = "";
     
     static DBHelper dbhelper;
     ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data;
     ListAdapter la;
     
     static int[] id;
     static String[] RecipeName;
     static String[] Preview;
     
     
     
     /** This class is used to create custom listview */
     static class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      private LayoutInflater inflater;
      private Context ctx;
      
      public ListAdapter(Context context) {
       inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       ctx = context;
      }
      
      public int getCount() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return RecipeName.length;
      }
    
      public Object getItem(int position) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return position;
      }
    
      public long getItemId(int position) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return position;
      }
    
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       ViewHolder holder;
       
       if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtRecipeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtRecipeName);
        
        holder.imgPreview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        
        convertView.setTag(holder);
       }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }
       
       
       holder.txtRecipeName.setText(RecipeName[position]);
       
       int imagePreview = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(Preview[position], "drawable", ctx.getPackageName());
       holder.imgPreview.setImageResource(imagePreview);
       
       
       return convertView;
      }
      
      static class ViewHolder {
       TextView txtRecipeName;
       ImageView imgPreview;
      }
      
     }
    
     
        **/** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.recipes_list);
            
            
            // Create the interstitial.
         interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
         interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7676436769471442/4006302017");
    
         // Create ad request.
         AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    
         // Begin loading your interstitial.
         interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);
         
         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           
                /*
                 * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
                 * want to show case your app logo / company
                 */
     
                public void run() {
                    // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                    // Start your app main activity
                 displayInterstitial();
                }
            }, 30000);
         
         AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
         AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("6EF305EAD8E00C37BCACF9D2505F9CCF").build();
         mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);**
            
            dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
            la = new ListAdapter(this);
            
            imgAbout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAbout);
            imgSearchNav = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSearchNav);
            btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
            edtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
            lytSearchForm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lytSearchForm);
            listRecipes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRecipes);
            prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
            txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);
         //   ads = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ads);
            
    
      //Ads.loadAds(ads);
            
            /**
             * when this app's installed at the first time, code below will
             * copy database stored in assets to
             * /data/data/com.recipes.app/databases/
             */
            try {
       dbhelper.createDataBase();
      }catch(IOException ioe){
       throw new Error("Unable to create database");
      }
      
            /** then, the database will be open to use */
      try{
       dbhelper.openDataBase();
      }catch(SQLException sqle){
       throw sqle;
      }
      
      new getDataTask().execute();
            
      
      listRecipes.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
         long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        /**
         * when one of item in the list is clicked, this app will access 
         * RecipeDetail.class. it also send id value to that class
         */
        Intent i = new Intent(RecipesList.this, RecipeDetail.class);
        i.putExtra("id_for_detail", id[position]);
        startActivity(i);
       }
      });
            
      
            
            imgSearchNav.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        /** this code is used to hide and show the search form */
        if(lytSearchForm.getVisibility() == 8){
         lytSearchForm.setVisibility(0);
         imgSearchNav.setImageResource(R.drawable.nav_down);
        }else{
         lytSearchForm.setVisibility(8);
         imgSearchNav.setImageResource(R.drawable.nav_up);
        }
       }
      });
            
            btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RecipeNameKeyword = edtSearch.getText().toString();
        try{
         dbhelper.openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
         throw sqle;
        }
        new getDataTask().execute();
       }
      });
            
            imgAbout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        /** when about icon is clicked, it will access AboutApp.class */
        Intent i = new Intent(RecipesList.this, AboutApp.class);
        startActivity(i);
       }
      });
        }
        
        /** this class is used to handle thread */
        public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
         
         getDataTask(){
          if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
           prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
        txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
          }
         }
         
         @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          
         }
         
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       getDataFromDatabase(RecipeNameKeyword);
       return null;
      }
         
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
       if(id.length > 0){
        listRecipes.setVisibility(0);
        listRecipes.setAdapter(la);
       }else{
        txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
       }
       dbhelper.close();
      }
        }
        
        /**
         * this code is used to get data from database and store them
         * to array attributes
         */
        public void getDataFromDatabase(String RecipeNameKeyword){
         data = dbhelper.getAllData(RecipeNameKeyword);
         
         id = new int[data.size()];
         RecipeName = new String[data.size()];
         Preview = new String[data.size()];
         
         
         for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
          ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(i);
          
          id[i] = Integer.parseInt(row.get(0).toString());
          RecipeName[i] = row.get(1).toString();
          Preview[i] = row.get(2).toString().trim();
          
          
         }
        }
       
       @Override
       public void onDestroy() {
       if (ads != null) {
       ads.destroy();
       }
      super.onDestroy();
    
     }
        
        @Override
     public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
     {
         // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
         super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     }
      //Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
       public void displayInterstitial() {
         if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
           interstitial.show();
         }
       }
        
    }
```

---

[recipe_Detail.xml][3]

```
 RecipesDetail.java :
```

---

```js
   package com.villagetagh.halawiyatlaid;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
    import com.villagetagh.halawiyatlaid.R;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Html;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.ScrollView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    public class RecipeDetail extends Activity {
     
     TextView txtRecipeName, txtPrepTime, txtCookTime, txtServes, txtSummary, txtIngredients, txtDirections;
     ImageView imgPreviewDetail;
     ProgressBar prgLoading;
     ScrollView sclDetail;
       
     
     DBHelper dbhelper;
     ArrayList<Object> data;
     int id;
     String RecipeName, Preview, PrepTime, CookTime, Serves, Summary, Ingredients, Directions;
     
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.recipe_detail);
      
      
    
       AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("6EF305EAD8E00C37BCACF9D2505F9CCF").build();
          mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
      
      Intent i_get = getIntent();
      id = i_get.getIntExtra("id_for_detail", 0);
      
      
      dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
      
      txtRecipeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRecipeName);
      txtPrepTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrepTime);
      txtCookTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCookTime);
      txtServes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtServes);
      txtSummary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSummary);
      txtIngredients = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIngredients);
      txtDirections = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDirections);
      imgPreviewDetail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreviewDetail);
      prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
      sclDetail = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sclDetail);
    
      
      try{
       dbhelper.openDataBase();
      }catch(SQLException sqle){
       throw sqle;
      }
      
      new getDetailTask().execute();
      
     }
     
     /** this class is used to handle thread */
     public class getDetailTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
         
         
         @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          
         }
         
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       getDetailFromDatabase();
       return null;
      }
         
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
       sclDetail.setVisibility(0);
       showDetail();
       dbhelper.close();
      }
        }
     
     /**
         * this code is used to get data from database and store them
         * to attributes
         */
     public void getDetailFromDatabase(){
          ArrayList<Object> row = dbhelper.getDetail(id);
          
          RecipeName = row.get(0).toString();
          Preview = row.get(1).toString();
          PrepTime = row.get(2).toString();
          CookTime = row.get(3).toString();
          Serves = row.get(4).toString();
          Summary = row.get(5).toString();
          Ingredients = row.get(6).toString();
          Directions = row.get(7).toString();
         }
     
     /**
      * then set those values of attributes to the views
      */
     public void showDetail(){
      txtRecipeName.setText(RecipeName);
      int imagePreview = getResources().getIdentifier(Preview, "drawable", getPackageName());
      imgPreviewDetail.setImageResource(imagePreview);
      txtPrepTime.setText("Prep time : "+PrepTime);
      txtCookTime.setText("Cook time : "+CookTime);
      txtServes.setText("Serves : "+Serves);
      txtSummary.setText(Html.fromHtml(Summary));
      txtIngredients.setText(Html.fromHtml(Ingredients));
      txtDirections.setText(Html.fromHtml(Directions));
     }
     
     @Override
       public void onDestroy() {
       
      super.onDestroy();
    
     }
     
     @Override
     public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
     {
         // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
         super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     }
    }
```

---

DB_Helper.java :

---

```js
    package com.villagetagh.halawiyatlaid;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
      
        private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.villagetagh.halawiyatlaid/databases/";
     
        private final static String DB_NAME = "db_recipes";
     public final static int DB_VERSION = 1;
        public static SQLiteDatabase db; 
     
        private final Context context;
        
     private final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_recipes";
     private final String ID = "id";
     private final String RECIPE_NAME = "recipe_name";
     private final String IMAGE_PREVIEW = "image_preview";
     private final String PREP_TIME = "prepare_time";
     private final String COOK_TIME = "cook_time";
     private final String SERVES = "serves";
     private final String SUMMARY = "summary";
     private final String INGREDIENTS = "ingredients";
     private final String DIRECTIONS = "directions";
     
     
        public DBHelper(Context context) {
     
         super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
        } 
     
        public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
     
         boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
         SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;
    
     
         if(dbExist){
          //do nothing - database already exist
          deleteDataBase();
          try {
           copyDataBase();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              throw new Error("Error copying database");
             }
         }else{
          db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase();
          db_Read.close();
     
             try {
           copyDataBase();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              throw new Error("Error copying database");
             }
         }
     
        }
     
        private void deleteDataBase(){
         File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
         
         dbFile.delete();
        }
       
        private boolean checkDataBase(){
     
         File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    
         return dbFile.exists();
         
        }
     
        
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
         
         InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
     
         String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
     
         OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
         
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int length;
         while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
          myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
         }
     
         myOutput.flush();
         myOutput.close();
         myInput.close();
     
        }
     
        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
         String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
         db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
     
        @Override
     public void close() {
         db.close();
     }
     
     @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     
     }
     
     @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     
     }
     
     /** this code is used to get all data from database */
      public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllData(String RecipeNameKeyword){
      ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
     
      Cursor cursor = null;
     
      if(RecipeNameKeyword.equals("")){
       try{
        cursor = db.query(
          TABLE_NAME,
          new String[]{ID, RECIPE_NAME, IMAGE_PREVIEW, COOK_TIME},
          null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
     
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
         do{
          ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();
          
          dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
          dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
          dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));
          dataList.add(cursor.getString(3));
      
          dataArrays.add(dataList);
         }
        
         while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
       }catch (SQLException e){
        Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }else{
       try{
        cursor = db.query(
          TABLE_NAME,
          new String[]{ID, RECIPE_NAME, IMAGE_PREVIEW, COOK_TIME},
          RECIPE_NAME +" LIKE '%"+RecipeNameKeyword+"%'",
          null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
     
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
         do{
          ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();
      
          dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
          dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
          dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));
          dataList.add(cursor.getString(3));
      
          dataArrays.add(dataList);
         }
        
         while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
       }catch (SQLException e){
        Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
      return dataArrays;
     }
     
      /** this code is used to get data from database base on id value */
      public ArrayList<Object> getDetail(long id){
      
      ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
      Cursor cursor;
     
      try{
       cursor = db.query(
         TABLE_NAME,
         new String[] {RECIPE_NAME, IMAGE_PREVIEW, PREP_TIME, COOK_TIME, SERVES, SUMMARY, INGREDIENTS, DIRECTIONS},
         ID + "=" + id,
         null, null, null, null, null);
     
       cursor.moveToFirst();
     
       if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        do{
         rowArray.add(cursor.getString(0));
         rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
         rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2));
         rowArray.add(cursor.getString(3));
         rowArray.add(cursor.getString(4));
         rowArray.add(cursor.getString(5));
         rowArray.add(cursor.getString(6));
         rowArray.add(cursor.getString(7));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }
     
       cursor.close();
      }
      catch (SQLException e) 
      {
       Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     
      return rowArray;
     }
    }
    
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYeU0.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggmBu.png
      [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/80F5j.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to store the number of times the user has gone to the recipe details in an int variable on your List activity and increment it each time the user goes to the details page (in your onItemClickListener).

You'll then need to override the onResume of your RecipeList page to check this value, if it matches if  it's the value you want then show an ad and reset it to 0.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (detailViews >= 3) {
        // show ad
        detailViews = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't put this code because i'm beginner in java please can you edit that on RecipesList.java and paste the result

Comment: What I gave you was practically everything you need. Here's the RecipeList with the changes needed, you just need to add the interstitial ad code to the onResume [link](http://pastebin.com/raw/ML01rXF9)

Comment: i'm so sorry for lose your time :(
Now is working but just in first time i mean is working just after 3 return from detail_recipes but when i try this in second time unfortunately is doesn't work never [link](http://pastebin.com/raw/JqmNfPgD)

Comment: I'd start be debugging to see if the detailsViewed is resetting and incrementing correctly after the first ad. I suspect however it might be something to do with the if statement in your display interstitial function.